# How can I use Regex in helpgrep?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, gvim, vimgrep, grep

I would like to use Regex in helpgrep.
For example, searching for lines or sections that contain two words. Something like `:helpg 'word1' & 'word4'` to find this line as my result:
`word1 word2 word3 word4`.
Or another example for lines or sections containing word1 `or` word4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexps in `:helpgrep`, you only need to provide a valid regular expression. Your `'word1' & 'word4'` does not do what you describe. To match both "word1" and "word4" on the same line or either of them, try the respective

```vim
:helpgrep word1.*word4
:helpgrep word1\|word4
```

The regexps explained:
The first line will match "word1" followed by any number of any character, followed by "word2".
The second line will match "word1" OR "word2", the `\|` being the OR operator in Vim's dialect of regular expressions (other dialects use a plain `|` so you may have seen this).

As I said, this works on *lines* and things get complicated quickly when trying to get matches within a section or paragraph. It's probably easier to search from there or actually reading the whole paragraph. I like doing so because I tend to learn new stuff this way.

A full description of regexps is beyond the scope of an answer on this site.
To familiarize yourself with (Vim's dialect of) regular expressions, read [`:help regexp`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#regexp).

Comment: what is the meaning of `\\` after word1?

Comment: It's not so much after word1 as it is in front of |. The `\|` is regexp's OR operator. Coincidentally, it's the first item in `:help regexp`. Please read it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, did you read the whole documents? Is it necessary in your opinion? I'm really disappointed to learn vim. It's huge....

Comment: I agree there are more accessible editors out there and not necessarily worse. Most of the time I read the section and sometimes the adjoining paragraphs. I don't think I have read all of Vim's documentation yet.

Comment: You can also use `\&` to denote a branch like in `:helpgrep .*word1\&.*word4` or `:helpgrep .*concats\&.*one or more` (Hint :-) ).